# Apache ANT homebrew install URL throwing 404

Tags: ant, homebrew

The url for ant:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/ant.rb
```

is throwing a 404 error. Can anybody supply the updated url to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type this command:

> brew install ant

http://blog.xk72.com/post/53124504531/homebrew-dupes-installing-ant-on-mac-os-x

Comment: oh score! Thanks wf9a5m75 :)